# why navigation doesn't work if using alignment property in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-design

I have created this page.

I have made some navigation by routes. But the problem is I want to change the position of my IconButton to the Center bottom of the page. That's why I am using the alignment parameter but as soon as I use that parameter my navigation stops working. But my Icon comes to my desired location but onPress function stop working.

I have the alignment code in the image.
Please guide what's wrong.

Thanks

Entire Code

```
      Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          alignment: Alignment(0, 50),

          child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_filled),
              color: Colors.yellow[900],
              iconSize: 80,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Second');
              }),
```

[Highlighted alignment codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy8jO.png)

Comment: I don't see any parameter in your code.. where is that?... Also, can you paste the code here instead of sharing a screen capture?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi In a Column, I have pass Container as the children and under the containter i have the pass IconButton as its child.

The problem is as soon as i am putting Alignment property under the container or IconButton my onPressed function stop working. if i remove the alignment property it again starts working

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I have added the codes there, I can't add the entire codes as it says i have reformat it. Please check the image to see the entire codes

Comment: What do you mean with "stop working"? Do you get any error? I don't see how aligment could affect navigation.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi no it doesn't throw any error. It's just when you click it won't navigate. onPress function doesn't work if the alignment is used.